# Custom app indicator works in Ubuntu however fails to work when I change Ubuntu to Gnome from login boot menu

Tags: python, ubuntu, gtk, gnome, pygobject

I have written an app indicator that works fine when I boot into Ubuntu from login boot menu. 
But if I change it to GNOME like this -
[image]

then it doesn't appear. The script runs, but nothing is visible on the top bar/ app-indicator bar.
Any idea why is this happening?
The basic structure of the app-indicator is like this-

```
import random
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator

APPINDICATOR_ID = 'myappindicator'

def change_label(ind_app):
    text = 'Hello world, what a beautiful day'.split()
    t = random.choice(text)
    print(t)
    ind_app.set_label(t , '')
    return True

def quit(source):
    Gtk.main_quit()

ind_app = appindicator.Indicator.new(APPINDICATOR_ID, Gtk.STOCK_INFO, appindicator.IndicatorCategory.SYSTEM_SERVICES)
ind_app.set_status(appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)

# create a menu
menu = Gtk.Menu()
menu_items = Gtk.MenuItem("Exit")
menu.append(menu_items)
menu_items.connect("activate", quit)
menu_items.show_all()
ind_app.set_menu(menu)
GLib.timeout_add(1000, change_label, ind_app)
Gtk.main()
```

NOTE: The app is written in Python 3.6.6

Comment: Seems like Gnome and AppIndicator refuse to work with each other [unless forced to](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/use-indicator-applets-gnome-shell).

Comment: @hidefromkgb I just tested the extension mentioned in that article. And indeed, my custom app-indicator did show up. However I'd like to have all the necessary code within my script itself. I do not want to rely on third party code. Any ideas on how to achieve that using Python itself?

Comment: No idea, unfortunately =(